# Delete an element in array if exist and add element if not exist

Tags: php

I have a text tag with "-" and "," seperators...
I need to explode array with "-" tags first and search for an item in that tags.

.than after found which item I am looking for than I will explode that with "," seperators..
.than ı will search for an item in that tag.. until here everything ok..

the problem is that ;

if element exist delete that element and than rearray everything with "," tags than "-" tags again..
else element not exist add that element to array and than rearray everythin with "," tags than "-" tags again..

here is what I have :

```
    <?php
$cars       = "product_1-Volvo,BMW,Toyota-product_2-lkb_1,lkb_2,lkb_3-product_3-pla_1,pla_2,pla_3"; 
$urun_grubu = "product_1";
$urun_adi   = "BMW";

$carsa          = explode("-",$cars);
$findvaluea     = array_search($urun_grubu,$carsa);
$carsa_degisim  = $findvaluea+1;
$carsb          = explode("," , $carsa[$carsa_degisim]);
$findvalueb     = array_search($urun_adi,$carsb);


array_splice($carsb, $findvalueb, 1); 
$carsc  ="";
$countb = count($carsb);
$i=0;
while ($i<$countb)
{
$carsc .= "," . $carsb[$i];
$i = $i+1;
}

$new_str  = str_replace($carsa[$findvaluea+1], $carsc, $carsa);


$countnew = count($new_str);
$i=0;
while ($i<$countnew)
{
$carsca .= $new_str[$i].",";
$i = $i+1;
}

echo $carsca;

?>
```

output is =

```
"product_1,,Volvo,Toyota,product_2,lkb_1,lkb_2,lkb_3,product_3,pla_1,pla_2,pla_3,"
```

I think there must be easiet and more effective ways for that.. do anyone have any idea for that?

Comment: It doesn't help that you use two languages in your variable names. Variables have names to make clear what they contain. I have to use Google translator to decipher the Turkish. It also took me a while to understand that `$carsa` is English: "cars a".

Comment: so what is your solution to help that question?

Comment: Use one language, and for Stack Overflow that should be English. Also, be consistent when naming variables, you use `$urun_adi` so you should use `$cars_a`, not `$carsa`.

Comment: thanks for general advices... still anything about main question?

Comment: Sorry no, it is unclear, to me, what your code is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: Your shown desired output makes little sense - there aren't even any `-` in there any more, you just joined _everything_ together with commas now (but that is not what you _said_ you wanted.) Also, _explain_ why `product_1-Volvo,BMW,Toyota` became `product_1,,Volvo,Toyota` - so by "deleted" you actually meant, replace this with an empty string? But why did the position also move? `BMW` was _between_ `Volvo` and `Toyota`, but now the "empty" element has apparently moved into the first position - why?

Answer (score 0):

here is what is my solution :

```
    <?php
$cars           = "product_1-tor_1,tor_2,tor_3-product_2-lkb_1,lkb_2,lkb_3-product_2-pla_1,pla_2,pla_3"; 
$product_group  = "product_1";
$product_name   = "aaa";

$carsa          = explode("-",$cars);
$counta         = count($carsa);
$findvaluea     = array_search($product_group,$carsa);
$carsa_degisim  = $findvaluea+1;
$carsb          = explode("," , $carsa[$carsa_degisim]);
$findvalueb     = array_search($product_name,$carsb);
$arraya         = "";

if (is_int($findvalueb))
{
    $replacements   = array($findvalueb => "");
    $sondurum       = array_replace($carsb, $replacements);
    $countb         = count($sondurum);
    $j=0;
    while ($j<$countb)
    {
      $arraya .= $sondurum[$j] . ","; 
    $j=$j+1;
    }
    $arraya     = substr($arraya, 0, -1);
}
else
{
    $countb         = count($carsb);
    $j=0;
    while ($j<$countb)
    {
      $arraya .= $carsb[$j] . ","; 
    $j=$j+1;
    }
    $arraya .= $product_name  ;
}
   
   
$array ="";
$i=0;
while ($i<$counta)
{
    if ($i==$findvaluea+1)
    {
        $array .= $arraya ."-"; 
    }
    else
    {
        $array .= $carsa[$i] ."-"; 
    }

$i=$i+1;
}
$array      = substr($array, 0, -1);
$array      = str_replace(",,",",",$array);
$array      = str_replace("-,","-",$array);
$array      = str_replace(",-","-",$array);

echo $array;

?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).